# Probate in Pennsylvania

Tags: united-states, inheritance, law, estate-planning, pennsylvania

My husband and I have named our daughter as beneficiary to all our financial accounts. After our death will she be able to get the money without probate? We live in Pennsylvania. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use a lawyer to write your will?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid probate costs, hassle, or both? An estate planning attorney may be more expensive than probate unless you have a large or complex estate.

Comment: is the child a minor? That could add a complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, that was enough.  My dad died about 5 years ago, and I was the beneficiary of his IRA.  The custodian transferred the money to me, no probate involved, and it was all very easy.

Your mileage may vary...